# Jasper Reports 6: Extra Space between fields

Tags: jasper-reports

I am working on Jasper report, which has page header with multiple detail bands.
Page Header has headers for my report and then detail band has field row wise.
But when report is generated there is extra space between rows.

For eg:- Row1 -- Data1 Data2 Data3 (From Detail band 1)
(Space)
(Space)
Row2 -- Data1 Data2 Data3  (From Detail band 2)

Don't need this space between rows. Any solution for this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help you:

Set Jaspersoft Studio properties for "Text field" or "Static text" as follows:

1. Line spacing for Proportional
2. Line Spacing Size to 0.4 (or similar)

XML Should be:

```
<textElement>
<font fontName="Courier"/>
<paragraph lineSpacing="Proportional" lineSpacingSize="0.4"/>
</textElement>
```